# Never Displays the first row

Tags: php

When I run the code in $Date within phpmyadmin it returns the correct number of rows but on the page it will never display the first row for some reason and I know it is not the numbering being off because my laptop Id is different for the two rows

```
function select_History_Date($link){

     $status = '';
     $i = 1;

     $date = "SELECT Student_Id, Loaner_Laptop_Id, HDD_Id, "
        . "Phone_Id, date_returned " 
        . "FROM equipment_history WHERE Loaner_Laptop_Id "
        . "IS NOT NULL OR HDD_Id IS NOT NULL OR Phone_Id IS NOT NULL";

$ret = mysqli_query($link, $date);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (!$ret) {
    die('Could not execute select statement:' . mysqli_errno($link));
} else {
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $status .= '<tr>';
    $status .= '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
    if (is_null($row1['date_returned']) && is_null($row1['HDD_Id']) && is_null($row1['Phone_Id'])){
        $status .= '<td><a href="ReturnLaptop.php?laptopId=' . 
                 $row1['Loaner_Laptop_Id'] . '&studentId='. 
                 $row1['Student_Id']. '">'. 'Return'. '</td>';
         } elseif (is_null($row1['date_returned']) && is_null($row1['HDD_Id']) && is_null($row1['Loaner_Laptop_Id'])){
        $status .= '<td><a href="ReturnPhone.php?phoneId=' . 
                 $row1['Phone_Id'] . '&studentId='. 
                 $row1['Student_Id']. '">'. 'Return'. '</td>';
         }elseif (is_null($row1['date_returned']) && is_null($row1['Phone_Id']) && is_null($row1['Loaner_Laptop_Id'])){
        $status .= '<td><a href="ReturnHDD.php?hddId=' . 
                 $row1['HDD_Id'] . '&studentId='. 
                 $row1['Student_Id']. '">'. 'Return'. '</td>';
         }else{
        $status .= '<td>' . $row1['date_returned'] . '</td>';
        }
        $status .= '</tr>';

        $i++;

        return $status;

        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

is reading the first row of data from your result. But then you are not doing anything with it before you do

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

which overwrites the data with the values from the second row. You need to delete the first line.